# How to bring back an environment from Conda which had been removed earlier?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, conda

In Windows Server 2012 R2 We had 3 environments in Conda earlier-

```
1. <base>
2. <py_27>
3. <py_3>
```

Now we have-

```
1. <base>
2. <py_36>
```

We need to bring back py_27. If possible, How do I do it ?

Comment: can you build a new environment with environment.yml?

Comment: @b0lleb if I do that than I have to do from scratch including libraries

Comment: @b0lleb can you tell me whats your suggestion..? that may work for me

Comment: if you have the environment file: conda env create -f environment.yml. If you dont and the force is with you, you can try to restore the environemnts: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#restoring-an-environment

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new environment with the version of python that you need, something like:

`conda create --name NameYourEnv python=2.7`

And you will have a clean python=2.7 environment.

Furthermore if you need additional modules just add them in the command:

`conda create --name NameYourEnv python=2.7 tensorflow ipykernel nb_conda`

NB: You can either call a module just by his name or specify its version. Conda will manage all the dependences and compatibility issues.

NBB: Mind that some packages will be available in other channels, like conda-forge, in that case you need to specify the channel adding `-c conda-forge` to the command.

Comment: The question was how to restore a deleted environment. You answered how to create a blank new one

Comment: That's what I said, I assumed yours were "blank envs" with the python version you generally use in Conda, guess I was wrong. Depending how did you delete the environment, you might still have it in the folder:  anaconda3/envs/ , but don't know how to bring that back to life, sorry for the missunderstanding ;)